How to find a distribution $u \in D'(\mathbb{R})$ such that $u(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x > 0$ and $u(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$?
Title:
How to find a distribution $u \in D'(\mathbb{R})$ such that $u(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x > 0$ and $u(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$?
Body:
I'm working on a problem from Introduction to the Theory of Distributions by G. Friedlander and M. Joshi (Chapter 1, Second Edition), and I'm looking for a distribution $u$ in the dual space of test functions $D'(\mathbb{R})$ that satisfies the following conditions:

$u(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x > 0$,
$u(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$.

I understand that the function $\frac{1}{x}$ has a singularity at $x = 0$, and I am wondering how to define a distribution that captures this behavior.
Is the distribution $u(x) = \frac{H(x)}{x}$ (where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function) a valid solution? What are the continuity properties of this distribution? Specifically, how does this distribution behave near $x = 0$, and is it regularized in some way to handle the singularity?

Can you find a function such that it's derivative is $u$?

@md2perpe, I was thinking about the function defined as
$$
f(x) = 0 \quad \text{for } x < 0, \quad f(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{1}{s} , ds \quad \text{for } x > 0,
$$
with $ x_0 > 0 $. This function is defined almost everywhere and is measurable since it is continuous almost everywhere. However, I am uncertain whether this function can be interpreted as a distributional limit of some sequence of functions or other distributions. This way I would have concluded.

And what is $\int \frac1s,ds$?

$u(x)=\frac{H(x)}{x}$ is not a valid solution. It's not a distribution as it stands. How do you define $\langle u, \varphi\rangle$ if $\varphi(0)\neq 0$?

@md2perpe It is $f(x) = \ln(x) - \ln(x_0)$. Now, $\log(x/x_0)$ is a continuous function in ${ x> 0},$ and thus it is a distribution on the open set ${x > 0}$. If I define $f = 0$ outside the closure of ${  x > 0}$  set I obtain a distribution of $\mathbb{R}.$ This kind of extension is mentioned in the first paragraph about the localization of distributions. Nice, I have solved the problem, thanks! If you formuate (generate ;) ) an answer I would gladly award you points!

Since $\frac1x$ is not locally integrable, it's not straightforward to use that. Instead you can look at its primitive function $\ln x$ which is locally integrable.
So, just set $U(x)=(\ln |x|+C)H(x),$ where $C$ is some constant, and let $u=U'$ where the derivative is taken in a distributional sense. Explicitly,
$$
\langle u, \varphi \rangle
= -\langle U, \varphi' \rangle
= -\int_0^\infty (\ln x) \varphi'(x)\,dx
\\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(-[(\ln x)\varphi(x)]_\epsilon^\infty + \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac1x \varphi(x)\,dx \right)
\\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left( (\ln \epsilon)\varphi(\epsilon) + \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac1x \varphi(x)\,dx \right)
.
$$
Note that different choices of $C$ will give different $u,$ differing by a multiple of $\delta.$

why is the first integral legal and why does the last limit converge?

The first integral is legal since $\ln|x|\in L^1(\mathbb R).$ With Riemann integration it should actually be interpreted as $\lim_{\epsilon\to0,\ R\to\infty} \int_\epsilon^R (\ln x)\varphi'(x),dx.$

That should also explain the limits that you are asking about.

sorry to be picky, but just to clarify: $ \ln(\vert x \vert) $ is integrable in a neighborhood of $ 0 $, but it is not integrable over all of $ \mathbb{R} $. However, that's fine since the test functions are compactly supported. I'm sure you meant $ L^{1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}) $. Thanks so much for all your explanations!

Yes, I meant $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R).$ Was in a bit of hurry when I answered.
